# TimeBasedPartitioner, Rotate schedule interval, Rotate interval in kafka connect HDFS connector

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I would like to flush all the records that are in kafka topic for every hour, Which of this properties can help,So that the data arriving in the topic for an hour is completely available in a file or a partition?

I came to know that Rotate Schedule Interval breaks exactly one semantics during break down?does that mean there is no offset committing back to kafka connect when we use `rotate.schedule.interval.ms` and `rotate.interval.ms` do not flush all the data in topic?

Are these properties supporting exactly once semantics `rotate.interval.ms and TimeBasedpartitioner` as well?

Thank You!!

Comment: They each do what you ask. The scheduled one will truncate to the top of the hour rather than rotate hourly from when the process started.. I believe the HDFS WAL will prevent duplicates

Comment: Thank you!! My understanding is that if the rotate.schedule.interval.ms=3600000,for every hour (00:00,01:0,02:00) will it  flush all the data in topic and if  rotate.interval.ms=3600000 will wait for 1 hour from the last file commit to flush the data.
And for TimeBasedPartitioner with  partition.duration.ms=3600000 will flush all the records from the topics for every hour in a separate partition.
Is it correct ?

Comment: And if I want to have a daily partition in similar manner with TimeBasedPartition and to flush records exactly at 00:00 every day and will this flush all the records in topics till 23:59 yesterday? So that I can prevent yesterdays records being flushed today? @cricket_007

Comment: I would suggest hourly or less rather than daily in order to avoid OOM or buffering too long in general. In my experience using TimeBasedPartitioner, there still end up with timestamps in files that land outside a specific hour. But I use the RecordField extractor rather than default WallClock. Anyways, partition duration sets the file path format, then you seem to have your understanding correct otherwise

Comment: And In time based partitioner if the flush size is reached before the  partition.duration.ms time will it flush the records?
In case if we have also mention the rotate.interval.ms,will it ignore partition.duration.ms?

Comment: Yes. Also if you have an Avro message and the schema changes, it'll flush. You can go look at the rotate logic yourself... https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-storage-common/blob/master/partitioner/src/main/java/io/confluent/connect/storage/partitioner/TimeBasedPartitioner.java